# The relation between betti numbers and Tor functor?

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be finitely generated Module over the Polynomial ring $R=k[x_{1},..,x_{n}]$, then there is a free resolution of M of the form 
$$0\rightarrow F_{n}\rightarrow ...\rightarrow F_{0}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$ 
We can write the free modules in the form $F_{i}=\bigoplus_{j\in \mathbb{Z} } R(-j)^{\beta_{i,j}}$, these numbers $\beta_{i,j}$ are called betti numbers, my question is how to show that $$\beta_{i,j}= \dim_{k}\; \text{Tor}_{i}^{R}(M,k)_{j}$$ .

Comment: What is $S$?${}$

Comment: sorry, it is R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint.  In order to compute the Tor groups you're interested in, you have to apply $-\otimes_R k$ to your resolution then take homology.  The terms of your resolution are sums of (shifts of) free modules, so because $R\otimes_R k=k$, you understand all the terms in $F_* \otimes _R k$.  If your resolution is such that the images of the differentials $F_i \to F_{i+1}$ are contained in $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)F_{i+1}$, then the induced differential on $F_* \otimes _R k$ is zero.  That makes it easy to calculate homology, and therefore Tor...

Comment: I've never understood how $\mathrm{Im}(d_i) \subset (x_1, \dots, x_n)F_{i-1}$ implied the differential on $F_* \otimes_R k$ is zero. Can you explain this?

Comment: @user46372819 what is the action of $x_i$ on $k$?

Comment: $x_i$ acts as $0$ since the map defining the action $k[x_1,\dots, x_n] \to k$ sends $x_i \mapsto 0$. 

Now, for any monomial $x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ and $a \in k$, we have $x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n} \otimes a = 1\otimes x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}\cdot a= 1\otimes 0$. 

Now, any $f \in (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is a $k$-linear combination of monomials, so again we have $f \otimes a=0$. 

Therefore, for any $f \in (x_1,\dots, x_n)F_i$, we have $f \otimes a =0$.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: No you've got it :)

Comment: What is the definition of $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,k)_j$? I suppose it is related to the $i^\text{th}$ homology, but what is the $j$ at the end?

Comment: Presumably M is intended to be graded, in which case the tor groups inherit an internal grading and the subscript j denotes the component of degree j

Comment: I've come back to this after all these months because I still don't understand the $j$ part. I see how $\beta_i = \dim \mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,k)$, but I don't see how $\beta_{ij} = \dim \mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,k)_j$. How are we getting this?